# UIButton addTarget method...not working?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisegmentedcontrol, uiactionsheet

I have a class variable that's an instance of `UIActionSheet`, called actionSheet. I add an instance of `UIPickerView` as well as an instance of `UISegmentedControl`. Though when I tap the "Done" button (instance of UISegmentedControl), my class method dismissActionSheet is never called. Can anyone help me out?

```
//@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

-(IBAction)chooseTopicButtonPressed{


    actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.dataSource = singlePicker.dataSource;
    pickerView.delegate = singlePicker.delegate;

    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];


    UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Done"]];
    closeButton.momentary = YES;
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 6, 300, 30);
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    //dismissActionSheet NOT BEING CALLED FOR SOME REASON!!! 

    [actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];

    [actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];

    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
}


-(void)dismissActionSheet{
    NSLog(@"dismissActionSheet called");
    [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: That's a lot of misuse of controls. A `UIActionSheet` is meant for showing a menu of buttons. A `UISegmentedControl` is not really meant to be used as a general case button. One of these days, Apple might update the implementation of `UIActionSheet` and everyone using it the wrong way is going to have a lot of issues. Try using a real UIButton instead of `UISegmentedControl` or try using one of the buttons in the `UIActionSheet`.

Answer (score 2):

The method `dismissActionSheet` doesn't have any arguments so the `@selector` should be as follows:

```
[closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```